# Skype: see who's talking

Tags: macos, skype

Running Skype 6.15.330 on OSX 10.8.

During a conference call, if I onhover and keep moving the mouse cursor, I can see the names of the people and they become blue when they're talking.

Is there any way to keep that information on the screen, without resorting to keep moving the mouse cursor?

Comment: It says [here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-manage-conference-calls-with-skype.html) that `On a Mac, the sound meter level for the speaking participant increases`. I can't test it out though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK using a plug-in, there is [Microcone Voices for Skype](http://www.dev-audio.com/products/voices/), which would seem to be a valid solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a small subset of Skype in-game overlay settings under Settings> Calls> Advanced Settings. So long as you have checked "show current calls when Skype is in the background" and "show skype watermark during calls," then you should be able to see who is and isn't speaking while Skype is in the background (such as when you're playing games).